# Postfix/dovecot email sent but not received

Tags: email, ubuntu-12.04, postfix-mta, lan, dovecot

Please help! I'm trying to setup an internal mail server on LAN using Postfix and Dovecot. Everything seems to be configured fine, emails sent (and received on my gmail account) but never received on the local server (using Webmail by Squirrelmail).
I'm using an Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, which sends me notifications about my new emails but cannot read in Squirrelmail (I see sent messages, messages in trash, maybe Drafts [didn't check that] but no incoming messages in the Inbox folder).
Though It would be a badly configured webmail thing I logged in with Thunderbird, where the problem is the same. Looks like email is sent and received but Dovecot is unable to find it.

**Here's my Postfix configuration file (main.cf):**
    # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = <SERVERNAME>
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = <SERVERNAME>, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

**...and my dovecot configuration file (dovecot.conf):**
    ## Dovecot configuration file

```
# If you're in a hurry, see http://wiki2.dovecot.org/QuickConfiguration

# "doveconf -n" command gives a clean output of the changed settings. Use it
# instead of copy&pasting files when posting to the Dovecot mailing list.

# '#' character and everything after it is treated as comments. Extra spaces
# and tabs are ignored. If you want to use either of these explicitly, put the
# value inside quotes, eg.: key = "# char and trailing whitespace  "

# Default values are shown for each setting, it's not required to uncomment
# those. These are exceptions to this though: No sections (e.g. namespace {})
# or plugin settings are added by default, they're listed only as examples.
# Paths are also just examples with the real defaults being based on configure
# options. The paths listed here are for configure --prefix=/usr
# --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var

# Enable installed protocols
!include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol

# A comma separated list of IPs or hosts where to listen in for connections. 
# "*" listens in all IPv4 interfaces, "::" listens in all IPv6 interfaces.
# If you want to specify non-default ports or anything more complex,
# edit conf.d/master.conf.
#listen = *, ::

# Base directory where to store runtime data.
#base_dir = /var/run/dovecot/

# Name of this instance. Used to prefix all Dovecot processes in ps output.
#instance_name = dovecot

# Greeting message for clients.
#login_greeting = Dovecot ready.

# Space separated list of trusted network ranges. Connections from these
# IPs are allowed to override their IP addresses and ports (for logging and
# for authentication checks). disable_plaintext_auth is also ignored for
# these networks. Typically you'd specify your IMAP proxy servers here.
#login_trusted_networks =

# Sepace separated list of login access check sockets (e.g. tcpwrap)
#login_access_sockets = 

# Show more verbose process titles (in ps). Currently shows user name and
# IP address. Useful for seeing who are actually using the IMAP processes
# (eg. shared mailboxes or if same uid is used for multiple accounts).
#verbose_proctitle = no

# Should all processes be killed when Dovecot master process shuts down.
# Setting this to "no" means that Dovecot can be upgraded without
# forcing existing client connections to close (although that could also be
# a problem if the upgrade is e.g. because of a security fix).
#shutdown_clients = yes

# If non-zero, run mail commands via this many connections to doveadm server,
# instead of running them directly in the same process.
#doveadm_worker_count = 0
# UNIX socket or host:port used for connecting to doveadm server
#doveadm_socket_path = doveadm-server

# Space separated list of environment variables that are preserved on Dovecot
# startup and passed down to all of its child processes. You can also give
# key=value pairs to always set specific settings.
#import_environment = TZ

##
## Dictionary server settings
##

# Dictionary can be used to store key=value lists. This is used by several
# plugins. The dictionary can be accessed either directly or though a
# dictionary server. The following dict block maps dictionary names to URIs
# when the server is used. These can then be referenced using URIs in format
# "proxy::<name>".

dict {
  #quota = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
  #expire = sqlite:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
}

# Most of the actual configuration gets included below. The filenames are
# first sorted by their ASCII value and parsed in that order. The 00-prefixes
# in filenames are intended to make it easier to understand the ordering.
!include conf.d/*.conf

# A config file can also tried to be included without giving an error if
# it's not found:
!include_try local.conf

protocols = imap imaps pop3 pop3s
#disable_plaintext_auth = no
#default_mail_env = mbox:~/mail/
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

I tried EVERYTHING to make this work but no success. Some forums say I must create namespaces for the mail directories, others say I must tell procmail/sendmail where to copy local emails but none of them tell me where I should configure these.

I'm out of ideas, it is driving me insane and I'm about to give up. Simply nothing works. Never ever succeeded to set up fully functional internal mail server using these tools.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

dovecot -n outputs the following:

```
# 2.0.19: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.8.0-29-generic i686 Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS 
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = imap pop3
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Comment: can you please show the dovecot conf using the command 'dovecot -n'

Comment: dovecot -n outputs the code above in the update section

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to use `procmail` for local delivery? I would set `mailbox_command` do `/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver` as it's native delivery agent for `dovecot`. If you have to use `procmail`, give us the configuration of it. You need to make sure, `procmail` config is consistent with `dovecot` config (mainly the mailbox path which seems to be the problem)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions, not email deliverability questions. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam

Answer (score 1):

So i managed to actually make it send/receive took a little tweaking,
if you follow this tutorial by the letter you'll get it working,

http://www.samhobbs.co.uk/2013/12/raspberry-pi-email-server-part-1-postfix/

its for raspberry pi, but should work perfectly on ubuntu.

fyi .. I've noticed since im using a dynamic ip address for my postfix mail server,
and they are automatically routed to gmails spam folder because of the usage of a dynamic ip.
(according to the world wide web at least)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but I could make it work a couple of weeks ago. I can't remember already which config file I had to edit but as I remember I had to replace only 1 line to make it work then restart the whole MTA. I'll try to find out what it was and update this post with the solution.

Comment: @Robert you should provide your solution for future users like us.

Comment: @sonubreeze it was about 3 years ago I was trying to use the configuration above and it turned out to be a quite uncomfortable solution as changing configuration was a long process. I just wouldn't do it again. Now I can only recommend you to follow Theodor's solution as it is a very well step-by-step tutorial and I no longer have access to the virtual machine I was trying the above out on since I have changed my position. If I have to install a mail server again, I will try the MySQL-Postfix-Dovecot-Postfixadmin-Roundcube-SASL authentication from stratch. Thank you for your understanding!

Answer (score 0):

```
#myhostname = <SERVERNAME>
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

1- try using this configuration.
2- if using cloudflare add MX record pointing at your domain with key @

Comment: Thank you for your help! It was many years ago since I tried this but I have a working configuration on my own VPS now. However, the current configuration is a bit different now:
`mydestination =  localhost.$mydomain, localhost`
`mailbox_command` not set in `main.cf`
And I also prefer storing all virtualdomain and virtual mailbox stuff in the database instead of config files as it is a lot easier to manage.
Postfix and Dovecot might have received some updates since then as it was a lot easier this time (I mean a few months ago).

Answer (score 0):

This situation can be have many reason! One of them is that you probably choose postfix as procmail for local delivery.

Use this command for going to the postfix configuration wizard:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

Don't change any settings except "Use procmail for local delivery?"

Select "No" option and finish configuration by choosing previous settings.

You can test incoming emails by below command:

```
swaks --server example.com --to root@example.com
```

(swaks must be installed!)